# Why if two varieties are isomorphic are their coordinate rings also isomorphic??

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've seen an example of a line isomorphic to the parabola $\mathbb{V}(y-x^{2})$ and I realised the pullback $x \rightarrow t, y \rightarrow t^{2}$ means the function $x^{2}$ is congruent to $y$ because their difference is $1\cdot(y-x^{2})$; it doesn't yet make sense having two coordinates for one variety and one coordinate for the other and they're coordinate rings are isomorphic.

Comment: Without going to any specifics here (which you probably do want, which is why I'm making this a comment and not an answer): "coordinate ring of variety" is an _attribute_ of the thing (the variety)... which probably means that it's completely determined by (the isomorphism class of) the thing (the variety). If two things are isomorphic, all their attributes are "the same" (=isomorphic, here).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "having two coordinates for one variety and one coordinate for the other"? What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @AlexProvost One variety has functions of two variables restricted to it and another has functions of just one variable restricted to it; I'm really okay with having different number of coordinates & applying relations to their structures because algebraic geometry is one of my favorite subjects but the fact applying a relation/s onto the structure/s does make them isomorphic is mildly difficult to work out lately. It could be because they are "quasi-projective varieties" and my text refers to them as "varieties."

Comment: @Ohioskateboarder.7 Like Alex, I'm still not sure what the issue is exactly. My vague sense is that your understanding of the material has quite a few conceptual holes, making it hard for you to articulate yourself. You might do well to find someone more expert than yourself to talk to about this, e.g. by doing a reading course with some professor.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation; I'll try asking for one some time >_<  @JoshuaP.Swanson!

Comment: I just was thinking, if a parabola is in 3-dimensions and a line it is isomorphic to is in 2-dimensions, which are isomorphic "varieties".... the polynomial $x+y+z$ restricts to $x+z$ on that parabola if it's not into the $y$ dimension at all and the same is true for other miscellaneous functions with $y$ in them.
Sort of like how the kernel of the map from the coordinate ring of the affine space to a subvariety would be the ideal of polynomials equal to zero except just with much more other sets. The same is also true for even a parabola in all three of the dimensions then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and assume you're misunderstanding the term "coordinate ring".

It means the ring of regular functions on the variety. Those are generated by the coordinate functions, hence the name. For instance, the coordinate ring of the line is $\mathbb{C}[t]$ where $t$ is the only coordinate function. The coordinate ring of the parabola has two coordinate functions, $x$ and $y$, but for all points $(a, b)$ on the parabola, we have $b=a^2$, so the coordinate functions are related by $y(a, b) = b = a^2 = x(a, b)^2$. That is, as functions we have $y=x^2$. This is the only relation in the sense that the coordinate ring of the parabola is $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(y-x^2)$. This is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$, even though the number of coordinate functions you start with in either case differs.